# Git repository gets corrupted when I do a large commit: "Possible repository corruption on the remote side"

Tags: git, macos, osx-snow-leopard, git-clone

A friend of mine and I have been trying to use git for a project. It is hosted on his server, and I git clone it as:

```
git clone username@IP.ADD.RE.SS:/path/to/git/repos.git
```

Pretty standard stuff, and it works great for a while. But every time one of us has added a large commit (which git supposedly handles very well), of the order of 100MB or so, the git repository gets kind of broken. Basically, at this point I will be able to push new changes and pull other changes (I think), but when I try to clone the repository in a fresh location using that command above, I get an error message that says:

```
$git clone username@IP.ADD.RE.SS:/path/to/git/repos.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /local/path/to/repos/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 1455, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1235/1235), done.
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.s   
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

This has happened 3 or 4 times now, and it's always when I add a large commit. Any idea why this is happening? How can we fix it? We're both using Mac OSX Snow Leopard.

Thanks!
-M

Comment: Do you have sufficient disk space on the server?

Comment: Yeah, looks like there's a lot of room on the server. Doesn't appear to be a disk space issue...

Comment: It could conceivably be more relevant what the server's running than what your computers are. There's not an old version of git on either end, is there?

Answer (score 1):

Very late response here.  You'll probably need to get back onto the server and locate the repository there and from within the directory run:

```
git gc
```

or

```
git gc --aggressive
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the push to the remote server failing? Maybe there is some packet loss on the connection and delta's are incomplete. Try setting up a bare repository on your local machine to push to and clone from and tell if it's still breaking.

Comment: Hi Marco, yes, clone-ing the local version (which is the latest version) of the git repository in a local directory works fine.

git clone /path/to/local/git/repos/

Comment: Packet loss shouldn't be a problem, as any retransmissions are handled by the TCP layer. Packet loss is common on the internet, and TCP is designed to handle it.

Comment: It is possible - if local "bare" repos are committable but not the remote there may be an issue with the transport mechanism (are you using the Git Daemon, SSH, WebDav?) or the remote server configuration - INODES (Virtual Machine), or with the Remote Git Repo itself.